# Wp-admin not working on localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost

i've found a topic related to this question but i haven't found a solution.

I've installed mamp, and installed wordpress. Home page is working great, but i get error 500 in localhost/theme/wp-admin and wp-login.

I've found siteurl and home in database, and I have this two paremeters with correct url. ( I have no home in any of this parameters )

I have neither .htaccess.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Locate your MAMP php error log, and add the error message to your question.

Comment: PHP Warning:  Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in /Volumes/Web/Desarrollo/colorful/wp-includes/user.php on line 39
[26-Aug-2017 20:46:39 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'user_login' in /Volumes/Web/Desarrollo/colorful/wp-includes/user.php on line 54
Uncaught Error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets in /Volumes/Web/Desarrollo/colorful/wp-includes/user.php:54
Stack trace:
#0 /Volumes/Web/Desarrollo/colorful/wp-login.php(795): wp_signon('', '')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Volumes/Web/Desarrollo/colorful/wp-includes/user.php on line 54

Comment: Update WordPress. [This error](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37071) was fixed.

Answer (score 16):

First try to create .htaccess file from [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) page.

Next, try to reupload the `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` folders.

**Update:**

You mentioned in the comments you get the following error:

> cannot create references to/from string offsets in /wp-includes/user.php

It looks to me that you are using PHP 7 on an older WordPress version.

Try using the fix below:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/37071/fix-wp-login-error.patch

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Also once you login to the dashboard, I recommend to upgrade it to the latest WordPress version.

Answer (score 1):

You can access Wordpress admin page

`localhost/wp-admin`

or

`localhost/admin`